# Assign random password in email for forgot password in drupal

Tags: drupal

Im trying to find look into functionality for forgot password,right now drupal

sends a link when user enters a emailaddress or username

Instead i require a random password to be sent to the user when requested for

password.

I know there is a module recovery password,after installing .its not working

Can any one suggest me any module or How i can write a custom module for that ?

Comment: `Can any one suggest me any module` let me point to item 4 of  StackOverflows [strictly off-topic list](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 0):

There are few modules promising that feature (but I didn't try any):

https://www.drupal.org/project/rpt

https://www.drupal.org/project/genpass